# Azure function configuration to log everything without any sampling to the Application Insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app

I don't want any sampling and want to log all the data in `requests, customEvents, traces` and `exceptions`.

Will having the following `host.json` ensure that all of the data logged via a telemetry object inside the Azure function is present consistently on the respective AppInsight instance?

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the correct way to `disable sampling` in azure function.

On more thing, if you want to log all the kinds of data, you also need to set the [log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#log-levels) to `Trace`. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging) for how to set log level in `host.json`.